# Does DemandTools have "CONTAIN"/ "BEGINS WITH" matching functionality?

Tags: tools

Is anyone here using [DemandTools](https://www.crmfusion.com/demandtools/) for Salesforce?

I'm using the discovery function in Demand Tools. I would like to add a match that search for account number which "Contains"/ "Begins with" values that I have specified in my source report.

I tried using the "First XX" letters but that wouldn't help me as I have a variation counts of first numbers I want to search for.